# can not find out if the div element is already set in body in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

in my chrome extension I got an div, which I will add to the body of the current tab. I am listening to chrome.tabs.onUpdated. If this event is called, I execute a script inside content_scripts. In this function there I´ll wait till the document is ready with jQuery `$(document).ready(...)`.
I try to access

```
$("#div").length
```

and sometimes it returns 1 and sometimes 0. It should added to the body, if it´s not already there.

For some strange reasons, the onUpdated event is called twice on each page reload. Actually I found no way to check safely if the div was already added.

Edit: My Code:

inject.js:

```
var crendentials;
var mailInfo;

function doLogin(username, password)
{
    function verifyLogin(username, password)
    {
        $.get("www.example.com&login&username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
              function (data)
              {
                 if (!isNaN($.trim(data)))
                 {
                    crendentials = new Array();
                    crendentials[0] = username;
                    crendentials[1] = password;

                    chrome.storage.sync.set({ key: "example_toolbar", value: username + ";;;" + password});
                    chrome.storage.sync.set({ key: "example_toolbar_verified", value: 1});
                }
                else
                {
                   chrome.storage.sync.set({ key: "example_toolbar_verified", value: 0});
                }
              }
       );
    }
    if (typeof username === "undefined" || username === null || username === ""
        || typeof password === "undefined" || password === null || password === "")
    {
        var crentest;
        chrome.storage.sync.get("example_toolbar",
                               function (value)
                               {
                                  console.log("value von doLogin()", value.example_toolbar);
                                  crentest = value.example_toolbar;
                               }
                            );
        if (typeof crentest !== "undefined" && crentest !== null && crentest !== "")
        {
            chrome.storage.sync.get("example_toolbar",
                                    function (value)
                                    {
                                       crendentials = value.example_toolbar.split(";;;");
                                    }
                                );
        }
   }
   else
   {
      verifyLogin(username, password);
   }
}


function getMailInfos(callback)
{
    if (typeof mailInfo === "undefined")
    {
       $.get("http://www.example.com&mailapi=showmails",
             function (data)
             {
                 mailInfo = new Array();
                 var infos = data.split("|");
                 mailInfo.unread = infos[0];
                 mailInfo.total = infos[1];
                 callback();
             }
        );
    }
    else
    {
      callback();
    }

}

function getMails(callback)
{
    if (typeof mailInfo === "undefined")
    {
       getMailInfos(function ()
                   {
                      callback(mailInfo.unread);
                   }
        );
    }
    else
    {
       callback(mailInfo.unread);
    }
}

function renderText(textstr)
{
   var divText = document.createElement("div");
   addClass(divText, "toolbarText");
   var text = document.createTextNode(textstr);
   divText.appendChild(text);
  toolbar.appendChild(divText);
}

var mailAmountDiv;
function renderMail(callback)
{
   var mailIco = document.createElement("div");
   addClass(mailIco, "mailIcon");
   mailAmountDiv = document.createElement("div");
   mailAmountDiv.id = "mails_unread";
   addClass(mailAmountDiv, "mailAmount");
   mailIco.appendChild(mailAmountDiv);
   getMails(function (value)
            {
               var mailAmount = document.createTextNode(value);
               mailAmountDiv.appendChild(mailAmount);
               toolbar.appendChild(mailIco);
               renderPlaceholderSmall();
               renderText(translations.notAttended + ": " + getNotRead());
            }
    );
}

function createToolbar(change)
{
   $(document).ready(function()
                    {

                       console.log("ist vorhanden: ", $("#Example-Toolbar").length);
                       if ($("#Example-Toolbar").length > 0)
                       {
                          // already created, stop working here
                          return;
                       }
                       doLogin();
                       toolbar = document.createElement("div");
                       toolbar.id = "Example-Toolbar";
                       renderMail(function()
                                  {
                                      renderPlaceholderLarge();
                                      renderSearch();
                                      renderPlaceholderSmall();
                                      renderRightIcons();
                                      $("body").css({"margin-top": "23px", "z-index": -1});
                                      //document.body.insertBefore(toolbar, document.body.childNodes[0]);
                                      $(toolbar).prependTo("body");
                                  }
                        );
                  }
            );
}
```

background.js:

```
function tabListener(tabId, changeInfo, tab)
{
   // exec script on current focused tabId
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,
                            {
                               code: 'createToolbar();'
                            }
              );
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(tabListener);
```

manifest.json (only neccessary parts):

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},

"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "file:///*/*",
    "storage"
],

"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "css": ["jquery-ui.css", "style.css"],
    "js": ["jquery-2.0.3.min.js", "jquery-ui.min.js", "inject.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
}]
```

Comment: can you share the HTML and javascript code that you have? or probably create a jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Some remarks: 1. You are injecting your files in every single web-page you visit. 2. You are calling `createToolbar()` at every single **onUpdated** event. Note, that in the "lifecycle" of page loading, many **onUpdated** events are fired (e.g. when status:loading, when status:complete, when the favicon is fetched etc). You need to check  `changeInfo` (e.g. `if (changeInfo.status && (changeInfo.status == "complete")) {...}`). 3. **The most important**: When asking for help regarding your code, please, provide a **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)** !

Comment: @alpham8: So, is your problem solved then ?Or should we look further into it ?